# how to create button (Show) in aspxgridview

Tags: asp.net

I have aspxgridview1. aspxgirdview1 was created Custombutton.
when i  click about custombuttion, aspxgridview2 load corresponding data base.
this following is aspxgridview1.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" KeyFieldName="Province_Id">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                    <EditButton Visible="True">
                    </EditButton>
                    <CustomButtons>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="show" Text="show">
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
                    </CustomButtons>
                </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Province_Id" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="1">
                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Province]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

aspxgridview2 contain attribute Province_Id, name,

Comment: unable to get the idea what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Shouldn't your 'show' button have a command associated with a handler that can be envoked on a click event?